# Drupal theme naming conventions for comment types

Tags: drupal, twig, conventions, theming

I set up a Drupal page, which has two different content-types. One is "articles", one is "reviews".

In my theme folder, I set up two node templates for these content types. node.html.twig (standard template - articles), and `node--reviews.html.twig`. 
When I add an article, `node.html.twig` is used, when I add a review, `node--reviews.html.twig` is used.

Now, it's possilbe to have different comments types too. I want to add the standard comment (`comment.html.twig`) for articles, and a custom comment type to reviews.

In Drupals theme naming documentation it's written, to name a template override like this: `comment--node-type.html.twig`. So I named my comment template `comment--node-reviews.html.twig`.

Is there anything else I have to do - apart from clearing the cache? 
Because I simply cant get it to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable [Twig Debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates), then you'll get template suggestions printed as HTML comments directly into the markup.

I did that and got the following output:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'comment__field_my_comment_field__article' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * comment--field-my-comment-field--article.html.twig
   * comment--field-my-comment-field.html.twig
   x comment.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/content/comment.html.twig' -->
```

So, the templates are supposed to be named like the following pattern:

```
comment--field-name-of-the-comment-field-in-the-content-type--content-type.html.twig
comment--field-name-of-the-comment-field-in-the-content-type.html.twig
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am bloody new to Drupal an Twig. I just thought of reading all the documentation ressources, but didn't think of a debugging functionality with suggestions. Great, and thanks again! ;)